# Make the background of a span inside of a div be full size using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a gameserver console for our gameserver control panel.
Now a small styling issue I have is that every odd line needs to a have a slightly brighter background.

Instead of this: 
[image]

I want this:
[image]

Code:

```js
showLoading('gameTerminal_content', '32', 'html', '');
```

```css
.gameTerminal_content_outputLine:nth-of-type(odd) { width:500px; background: #4C3C33; }
```

```html
    <div class="well-md" id="gameTerminal" style="background: #2A211C; height: 300px; max-width: 100%; overflow-y:scroll; font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace">
                   
    <p>
               
    <span id="gameTerminal_content" style="color:#80FF80; width: 100%;">
    
    <span class="gameTerminal_content_outputLine">Line 1</span><br /><br />
    <span class="gameTerminal_content_outputLine">Line 2</span><br /><br />
    <span class="gameTerminal_content_outputLine">Line 3</span><br /><br />
                    
    </span>
    
    </p>
                   
    <!--<input type="text" name="gameTerminal_input" style="background: #4C3C33; float: left; color: #FFFFFF; width: 90%; border:none; position: absolute; bottom: 0; outline: none;" />-->
    
    <div id="gameTerminal_scrollHeigth"></div>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your spans to be inline blocks if you want them to take up the width of the div. Just add:

`.gameTerminal_content_outputLine {     display: inline-block; }`

Snippet:

```js
showLoading('gameTerminal_content', '32', 'html', '');
```

```css
.gameTerminal_content_outputLine:nth-of-type(odd) { width:500px; background: #4C3C33; }
.gameTerminal_content_outputLine {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="well-md" id="gameTerminal" style="background: #2A211C; height: 300px; max-width: 100%; overflow-y:scroll; font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace">
                   
    <p>
               
    <span id="gameTerminal_content" style="color:#80FF80; width: 100%;">
    
    <span class="gameTerminal_content_outputLine">Line 1</span><br /><br />
    <span class="gameTerminal_content_outputLine">Line 2</span><br /><br />
    <span class="gameTerminal_content_outputLine">Line 3</span><br /><br />
                    
    </span>
    
    </p>
                   
    <!--<input type="text" name="gameTerminal_input" style="background: #4C3C33; float: left; color: #FFFFFF; width: 90%; border:none; position: absolute; bottom: 0; outline: none;" />-->
    
    <div id="gameTerminal_scrollHeigth"></div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: Exactly where I was looking for, thanks for actually reading what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just add style that targets even lines using `:nth-of-type(event)` that is similar and slightly brighter than your current one which targets odd elements :

```
.gameTerminal_content_outputLine:nth-of-type(odd) { 
     width:500px; 
     background: #4C3C33; 
 }
.gameTerminal_content_outputLine:nth-of-type(even) { 
     width:500px; 
     background: #5D4D44; 
 }
```

**Update**

I hadn't realized you wanted to get rid of the explicit padding between each row of elements. Since the elements are `<span>` elements, you would want to set them to set them to `display:block`:

```
.gameTerminal_content_outputLine {
      display: block;
}
```

which would render the content as seen in [this example](http://jsbin.com/docorir/edit?html,css,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: This is not what I asked for: I already now how to give the odd and even a different color. Look at the gyazo links I posted. Look at the difference.

Comment: Have you considered setting the `display:block` property on them? I've updated my response to reflect this change (as it's more apt to what you were looking for).

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. I had read in your initial response the phrase "I have is that every odd line needs to a have a slightly brighter background." and I thought that was the primary issue (as the image took a few takes to realize the spacing was the problem).

Answer (score 1):

You wants [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vtaeueg3/) ? (according to your pictures)

```
.gameTerminal_content_outputLine { display: block; width: 100%; }
```